# How to get connected iPhone name in Apple Watch programatically

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am just new in **Apple Watch** and want to know if there is possible way to get the connected device name and number (**It will be a single iPhone at a time as Apple docs says**)? Can we do it programmatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In your extension, which is connected and *runs on the iPhone*, you can get the current device's name using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]
```

After getting device name you can pass it to watch kit extension.

Comment: How we can get programmatically?

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]

Comment: But it will give the current device name. I want to get the connected iPhone name

Comment: Since your watch kit code runs on the iPhone it will be the name of the connected iPhone.

Comment: Can we get the phone number too

Comment: Not via public api so no for App Store apps